# Redirecionamento de saída

Tags: string, bash, shell-script

```
comando | tee -a saida.txt
```

Como faço para redirecionar apenas parte da saída de um comando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependo do output do comando executado pode utilizar o [grep](https://treinolinux.blogspot.ch/p/blog-page_27.html) (ou uma das suas variantes, `egrep` ou `fgrep`). Por exemplo:

```
comando | grep batata | tee -a saida.txt
```

No exemplo anterior, apenas as linhas que contêm a a palavra batata são passadas ao `tee`.

Dependendo do filtro (caso necessite da algo mais sofisticado), pode usar o `awk` ou `sed`.